# Get the position of a spring as a function of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

If I have a spring that I displace by $x$ from its equilibrium and then let go, what position will the spring be at after $n$ time. (taking friction into account)

I made a quick Illustration to explain the problem further:
[image]

We know that following Hoeke's law

$$F = -kx$$
with $k$ being the stiffness

since
$$F = ma$$

We can define the acceleration of the object like this

$$a = \frac{-kx}{m}$$

and also
$$a = \frac{\Delta  \mathrm{velocity}}{\Delta  \mathrm{time}} $$

This is the part where I get stuck, I'm not sure how to resolve this equation whilst also taking friction into account.

I found an article that seemingly addresses this but the solution seems insanely complicated for what I'm trying to do: https://physics.info/sho/

Ideally, I'd like to express it as a function of $\mathrm{time}, k,m,d, x$ so that I don't have to recalculate it after modifying any of these parameters.

Comment: If you're open to using Laplace transforms, which turn differential equations (such as $F=m\ddot x$) into simpler algebraic equations, to solve this problem, the process is described in [this note](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started out really well with your expression for the spring force and stating Newton's second law. To add friction into the mix we need to realize that the damping is proportional to the velocity of the oscillating mass. We could liken it to a similar system where the spring itself is frictionless but it is oscillating in a viscous fluid.

Writing out an expression for the friction force would give us;
$$ F = -bv $$

which would give us an expression for the forces in the system;
$$ ma = -bv - kx $$

Rewriting in terms of x, we have
$$ m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b \frac{dx}{dt} + kx $$

Which is a second-order homogenous differential equation.

To come at its solution, let's think of something that you already mentioned (in fact, you also drew it out). The spring should, with the right amount of damping, oscillate with decaying amplitude. We know that we can model decay using an exponential function and oscillation using a sinusoid so a solution to this differential equation could have the form
$$ x = e^{\alpha t}\cos {\beta}t  $$
I won't go into it here but this is a valid solution to the above differential equation. Now I am going to make one simplification to the above expression.
$$ x = e^{\lambda t}  $$
where we allow $ \lambda $ to be a complex number.

Plugging this expression into the differential equation and factoring out x gives
$$ (m{\lambda}^2 + b{\lambda} + k)x = 0 $$

which is quadratic in $ \lambda $. solving for $ \lambda $ gives us
$$ \lambda = -\frac{b}{2m} \pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{b}{2m}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{k}{m}\right)} $$

When $ \lambda $ is allowed  to be complex and ( $ b^2 < 4km $) we get the decaying sinusoid you drew in your diagram. The position of the mass m at time t with damping coefficient d is then given by
$$ x = A_0e^{-\frac{b}{2m}} \cos({\omega t + \phi}) $$
where $ A_0 $  and  $ \phi $ are parameters we can tweak to match the initial conditions of the system and $ \omega $ is defined as follows
$$ \omega = \sqrt{ \frac{k}{m} - \left(\frac{b}{2m}\right)^2 } $$

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! I assume the $b$ in your equations is equal to the displacement d, and t is time in seconds, correct? 
In that case what does $A_0$ stand for?

Comment: The b is equal to the damping coefficient. So it describes how much friction there is and how fast the decay will happen. A_0 stands for the Initial amplitude or how far from equilibrium the mass was at time t = 0

Comment: @cubefox If this answer answers your question in the best way, please accept it. (Checkmark underneath the vote-count)

Comment: Very good answer. IMO, better than mine. +1. Welcome to SE Mwila, you are off to an excellent start

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not sure how to resolve this equation whilst also taking friction into account.

This equation is called the simple harmonic oscillator and it does not take friction into account. If you want to take friction into account then you need to use the damped harmonic oscillator.

An explanation of the damped harmonic oscillator is here: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Oscillations/15.06%3A_Damped_Oscillations

Qualitatively, if you start with a simple harmonic oscillator and add just a little bit of friction then you will get an under-damped oscillator. This will have a period that is a little longer than the corresponding undamped oscillator, and the amplitude will decay exponentially. If you add too much friction then it will become over-damped. In this case it will not oscillate at all but will just gradually approach the equilibrium position.